# Trying to use data:url png as a custom cursor

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a custom cursor of a paintbrush icon. I found some code online to do this and it worked, but then I replaced their dataurl with the dataurl of the paintbrush icon I wanted and it stopped working.

```
.custom {
  cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto; 
}

</style>

<body style = "font-family: 'Open Sans';">
    <section class="first custom">
        <div>blablabla</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

For reference, this was the original data url that works when I replace my non-working paintbrush icon url with it.

```
url(data:image/png;base64,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)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of the image size. Keep in mind the cursor image needs to be at most 32x32px. 
 
Check the "Limitations" section https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property